# Loop over csv data

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to check for the video file names present in csv file. If name is found video should be skipped else video frames should be extracted

I have the script for frame extraction and video name is also getting written in the csv but i want to loop over the csv data everytime the script is run to check if the video name is present or not

import cv2
import glob
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import json
import sys
import csv
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from os.path import isfile,join
import pandas as pd

```
########################################## EXTRACT FRAMES FROM VIDEO###########################


def extractFrames(m):
    global vid_name

    vid_files=glob(m)
    complete_videos = get_completed_videos()
    new_vid_files = [x for x in vid_files if x not in complete_videos]

    for v_f in range(len(new_vid_files)):
        print("path of video========>>>>.",new_vid_files[v_f])

        v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])


        try:
            vid_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(new_vid_files[v_f])
        except cv2.error as e:
            print(e)
        except:
            print('error')
        #condition 
        fsize=os.stat(new_vid_files[v_f])
        print('=============size of video ===================:' , fsize.st_size)
        try:

            if (fsize.st_size > 1000):

                fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)      # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
                frameCount = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
                duration = frameCount/fps
                minutes = int(duration/60)
                print('fps = ' + str(fps))
                print('number of frames = ' + str(frameCount))
                print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
                if (duration > 1):
                    success,image = vidcap.read()


                    count=0

                    success=True

                    while success:

                        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"

                        success,image = vidcap.read()
                        if count % 10 == 0 or count ==0:
                            target_non_target(img_name, image)

                        count+=1          

                    vidcap.release()

                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        except:
            print("error")


        print('finished processing video ', new_vid_files[v_f])
        with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['Video_Name','Process']
            file_is_empty = os.stat("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\"+'video_info.csv').st_size == 0
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            if file_is_empty:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'Video_Name':vid_name,'Process':'done'})



def get_completed_videos():
    completed_videos = []
    with open("C:\\multi_cat_3\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\video_info.csv") as csv_file:

        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            for col in row:
                try:
                    completed_videos.append(row[col])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
    print(completed_videos[0])
```

If a csv file has videos A,B,C present then on adding video 4 to the folder and running the script first the video names present in the csv should be checked and then only video 4 should be processed instead of all the videos

Currently i am facing the below error while trying to loop over my csv data

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\multi_cat_3\models\research\object_detection\code_modification_test (1).py", line 276, in <module>
    extractFrames(x)
  File "C:\multi_cat_3\models\research\object_detection\code_modification_test (1).py", line 29, in extractFrames
    complete_videos = get_completed_videos()
  File "C:\multi_cat_3\models\research\object_detection\code_modification_test (1).py", line 105, in get_completed_videos
    print(completed_videos[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read a CSV line, you are reading a string (usually separated by commas), so you need to convert it to a list by splitting, so in your function get completed videos, you need to change your for loop as:

```
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        cols=row.split(",")
        for col in cols:
            try:
                completed_videos.append(col)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
```

Anyway, i would do it this way better:

```
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        cols=row.split(",")
        completed_videos.extend(col for col in cols)
```

**EDIT**

If, as you say, you already have a list in your row, then you cannot reference a list by it's column name, you should do it by it's index:

```
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        for col in range(0,len(row)):
            try:
                completed_videos.append(row[col])
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
```

Comment: Video_name Process
M_1_acqybirf done
 
M_1_bxcysevk done    ####currently this is how my csv looks like.So on splitting it with commas it returns an error saying     cols=row.split(",")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: The csv has 2 headers Video_name and Process. The entire data is below those headers

Comment: hey can u check my code above please? It is still processing the video whose name is present in the csv instead it should have processed only the new video i pasted in the folder after checking for the video names present in the csv..is something wrong in the logic?